# Socket only reads with breakpoint set

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I am writing a socket listener and testing it with SocketTest, and it only reads when a breakpoint is set. It connects with or without the breakpoint. I tried added a sleep in the while (infinite because it's on it's own thread).

With a breakpoint, it works perfectly every time, which makes me think it's a timing or buffer issue of some sort, and I could use some help pinpointing the cause. The exception blocks are empty (I just wrote the code) and will be added to, but they do not catch so it's not an exception issue. Here is the code:

```
public static void doSocket()
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(Globals.foxProAddress, Globals.foxProPort);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        try
        {
            serverSocket.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[100025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
                string dataFromFoxPro = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                if (!dataFromFoxPro.Equals(""))
                {
                    Payments.startTransaction(dataFromFoxPro);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get a better response here, try improving your code formatting (its almost impossible to read as is). In addition, C# style calls for {} on their own lines for any multi-line blocks. Also, what tells you its *not* working?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It might be working as intended, but the startTransaction(string) method consists purely of MessageBox.Show(input), and it only shows the alert when a breakpoint is set

Comment: are you *sure* there are no exceptions? if there's nothing to read yet, this will throw ioexceptions repeatedly forever.  what's with the strangely specific array length?  you never check how many bytes were read, there are so many questions i have here...

Comment: @JohnGardner Yes, you are correct, no exceptions fire at all ("empty" reads consist of "00000..n"). This is basically pasted code (I'm learning sockets), and the size of the byte array is what what in the example I found. I definitely welcome suggestions or demonstrations on how to improve the code above.

Comment: It seems that you assume that you receive a packet that contains all data from a send command. The problem is that the sent data may be received in separate packets.

Comment: well, first, i'd have the exception catch break.  if something fails, why keep reading?  second, `Read` is going to read however much data is available, which isn't guaranteed to be the full size of your buffer.  it might literally give you one byte.  what do you do then?  when not attached with the debugger, did your `.start` call fail?  you literally are doing no exception handling anywhere, so we don't even know what's going on.

Comment: Check the return value of the Read call...and pass it to GetString Method along with an offset of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return value of [Read() [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0.

With a breakpoint set, it it more likely that data arrives in the meanwhile.

You should also pass the index (`0`) and the number of bytes read into [GetString() [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/38b953c8%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

I'd also move the `clientSocket.GetStream();` outside the loop, just to make clear to the reader that you want to keep the stream during the whole loop. Otherwise someone could think that there's a `Dispose()` missing, which would destroy the stream.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I thought it had something to do with data retrieval timing. Do you (or anybody) have ideas on how to appropriate the read in the code above to give data time to arrive? I have tried, reluctantly, a sleep(500), and it still did not read properly.

Comment: @Wes the Read call will block until all or some of the data is received. Also look at the documentation on the MSDN link provided above. The example use DataAvailable property

Comment: exactly, *some*.  so maybe 1 byte of what Wes wants.  Wes, you're the only one who knows what your data looks like.  you'll probably need a `StringBuilder`, and then inside of your loop, you'll append results to that string builder until you know you have the appropriate amount of data.  then take that substring out of the stringbuilder and process it, leaving behind whatever other partial data is still left, continuing to append to it as necessary.

Comment: Or use the StreamReader Class

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem It sounds as though you know the ins and outs of socket listening, and I am inclined to think you have an ideal answer. What are the implications of your statement; that is, how can I go about fixing the sample code with your suggestion? If the read call is blocking, should I decrease the byte[] size, create a string outside the while that is checked and concatenated inside the while loop, or some third option I have not considered?   Just read above comments, thank you gentlemen, will do

Comment: @Wes i guess you got it all sorted out

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of what John Gardner suggests:

```
    public static void doSocket()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(Globals.foxProAddress, Globals.foxProPort);
            serverSocket.Start();
            TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int bytesRead;
            string buffer = "";
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[4096];

            while (true)
            {

                bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
                string dataFromFoxPro = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom, 0, bytesRead);
                buffer = buffer + dataFromFoxPro;
                // look at buffer and see if it has one or more complete "messages":
                while (buffer.Contains("something")) // made up protocol
                {
                    string msg = buffer.Substring(0, buffer.IndexOf("something")); // extract the message <-- completely made up
                    buffer = buffer.Remove(0, msg.Length); // remove the msg from the beginning of the buffer <-- pseudo-code!
                    Payments.startTransaction(msg);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is **very rough** code and is simply designed to give an overview of what the code might look like.